# retrieve value from hashtable with clone of key; C#

Tags: c#, hashtable, key, clone

I would like to know if there is any possible way to retrieve an item from a hashtable using a key that is identical to the actual key, but a different object. I understand why it is probably not possible, but I would like to see if there is any tricky way to do it.

My problem arises from the fact that, being as stupid as I am, I created hashtables with int[] as the keys, with the integer arrays containing indices representing spatial position. I somehow knew that I needed to create a new int[] every time I wanted to add a new entry, but neglected to think that when I generated spatial coordinate arrays later they would be worthless in retrieving the values from my hashtables.

Now I am trying to decide whether to rearrange things so that I can store my values in ArrayLists, or whether to search through the list of keys in the Hashtable for the one I need every time I want to get a value, neither of the options being very cool.

Unless of course there is a way to get //1 to work like //2!

Thanks in advance.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hashtable dog = new Hashtable();

            //1
            int[] man = new int[] { 5 };
            dog.Add(man, "hello");
            int[] cat = new int[] { 5 };
            Console.WriteLine(dog.ContainsKey(cat)); //false


            //2
            int boy = 5;
            dog.Add(boy, "wtf");
            int kitten = 5;
            Console.WriteLine(dog.ContainsKey(kitten)); //true;


        }
```

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with your design ...

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan, why would you say that?  What's wrong with looking up a value in a `Hashtable` when using a newly created but otherwise equal key instance?  This is a common scenario and is very well supported in .NET.

Comment: @Sam, the issue with the design is using a key that does not provide value equality semantics. An ideal key for a hashtable would 1) be immutable 2) override equals and 3) override gethashcode. Arrays meet none of those criteria.

Comment: I would say that point number 1 is by far the most important. Mutable hash keys lead to the possibility of *duplicate* hash keys. The other issues can be solved elsewhere, if need be.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you have two options.

1. Implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in the key classes.
2. Create a custom `IEqualityComparer` and pass it to the `Hashtable` constructor.

You'll want to implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` yourself when the implementations make sense for all usages of your custom class.  If they are only appropriate sometimes, then use a custom `IEqualityComparer` which has the same functionality but provides it separate from the class itself.  This second option also allows you to provide custom rules for non-custom key classes.

Comment: +1 for option 2 (since he can't very well inherit from `int[]`)

Comment: Another +1 for option 2. Though I'd strongly recommend changing the design of the app to use a more suitable key.